# Maven build using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I created a job to build the maven project, by configuring Jenkins as per standard conventions like:

svn repository URl: valid link

Under Build section:-

root pom: location of pom.xml file

goals and options: clean install

saved and started build

got console output as :

```
Parsing POMs ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ line 8, column 11
```

where line 8 is:

```
<version>${dsstextversion}</version>
```

if it is asking for version no., then how to invoke version no. into this ?

Comment: `dsstextversion` is in a profile? If yes, the profile is activated?

Comment: @Bruno..it is like <version>${dsstextversion}</version> inside the pom.xml file.

Comment: Yes, I know, my question is if the property `dsstextversion` is declared in some profile properties or in default properties. Can you show your pom or your effective pom?